# How to change multiple Date formats in same column?

Tags: r, date, format

What I've got so far is a dataframe column with dates in different character formats. A few appear in the `%d.%m.%Y` pattern, some in `%m/%d/%Y` :

```
data$initialDiagnose = as.character(data$initialDiagnose)
data$initialDiagnose[1:10]

[1] "14.01.2009" "9/22/2005"  "4/21/2010" "28.01.2010" "09.01.2009" "3/28/2005" "04.01.2005" "04.01.2005" "9/17/2010" "03.01.2010"
```

I want them as Date() in one format, but R refuses of course.
So I tried at first to change them by the separator:

```
data$initialDiagnose[grep('/', data$initialDiagnose)] = as.character.Date(data$initialDiagnose[grep('/', data$initialDiagnose)], format = '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Analog to the '.' dates. But it didn't work.

How can I change them all to one format, that I can work with them?

Answer (score 31):

Since [MattBagg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765386/8366499) in 2012, `lubridate` has added the `parse_date_time` function which is designed for exactly this situation and can resolve this problem in a single line:

```
library(lubridate) 

data <- data.frame(initialDiagnose = c("14.01.2009", "9/22/2005", 
        "4/21/2010", "28.01.2010", "09.01.2009", "3/28/2005", 
        "04.01.2005", "04.01.2005", "Created on 9/17/2010", "03 01 2010"))

parse_date_time(data$initialDiagnose, orders = c('mdy', 'dmy'))

 [1] "2009-01-14 UTC" "2005-09-22 UTC" "2010-04-21 UTC" "2010-01-28 UTC" "2009-01-09 UTC"
 [6] "2005-03-28 UTC" "2005-01-04 UTC" "2005-01-04 UTC" "2010-09-17 UTC" "2010-03-01 UTC"
```

The `orders=` argument is a character vector containing the possible date-time parsing formats in the order they should be tested. So by giving `c('mdy', 'dmy')`, lubridate will try to parse all strings as `Month, Date, Year` format. If it can't do that successfully (for example, the date `14.01.2009` won't work as there is no 14th month), it will try the next in the list.

The order in which it tries formats is a bit complicated, but you generally don't have to worry about it. `parse_date_time2` simply tries them in the order provided. `parse_date_time` takes a subset of the input strings and uses that as a training set to find the best performing set formats, which orders based on the function given by the `select_formats` argument, which by default prioritizes the most complex formats (ie, those with the most format tokens)

Comment: orders argument does not test them in the order these are given.  See help page

Answer (score 30):

I like lubridate for its ease of use:

```
library(lubridate) 

# note added ugly formats below
data <- data.frame(initialDiagnose = c("14.01.2009", "9/22/2005", 
        "4/21/2010", "28.01.2010", "09.01.2009", "3/28/2005", 
        "04.01.2005", "04.01.2005", "Created on 9/17/2010", "03 01 2010"))

mdy <- mdy(data$initialDiagnose) 
dmy <- dmy(data$initialDiagnose) 
mdy[is.na(mdy)] <- dmy[is.na(mdy)] # some dates are ambiguous, here we give 
data$initialDiagnose <- mdy        # mdy precedence over dmy
data
#   initialDiagnose
#       2009-01-14
#       2005-09-22
#       2010-04-21
#       2010-01-28
#       2009-09-01
#       2005-03-28
#       2005-04-01
#       2005-04-01
#       2010-09-17
#       2010-03-01
```

Comment: I appreciate / think the value of explicitly defining preference is huge here.

Answer (score 22):

```
a <- as.Date(data$initialDiagnose,format="%m/%d/%Y") # Produces NA when format is not "%m/%d/%Y"
b <- as.Date(data$initialDiagnose,format="%d.%m.%Y") # Produces NA when format is not "%d.%m.%Y"
a[is.na(a)] <- b[!is.na(b)] # Combine both while keeping their ranks
data$initialDiagnose <- a # Put it back in your dataframe
data$initialDiagnose
[1] "2009-01-14" "2005-09-22" "2010-04-21" "2010-01-28" "2009-01-09" "2005-03-28" "2005-01-04" "2005-01-04" "2010-09-17" "2010-01-03"
```

Additionnaly here's the preceding method adapted to a situation where you have three (or more) different formats:

```
data$initialDiagnose
[1] 14.01.2009 9/22/2005  12 Mar 97  4/21/2010  28.01.2010 09.01.2009 3/28/2005 
Levels: 09.01.2009 12 Mar 97 14.01.2009 28.01.2010 3/28/2005 4/21/2010 9/22/2005

multidate <- function(data, formats){
    a<-list()
    for(i in 1:length(formats)){
        a[[i]]<- as.Date(data,format=formats[i])
        a[[1]][!is.na(a[[i]])]<-a[[i]][!is.na(a[[i]])]
        }
    a[[1]]
    }

data$initialDiagnose <- multidate(data$initialDiagnose, 
                                  c("%m/%d/%Y","%d.%m.%Y","%d %b %y"))
data$initialDiagnose
[1] "2009-01-14" "2005-09-22" "1997-03-12" "2010-04-21" "2010-01-28" "2009-01-09" "2005-03-28"
```

Comment: Is this function robust? Presumably the date formats as argument should be ordered by frequency of occurrence in the initialDiagnose. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the frequency of occurrence is an issue as long as there is no mutually ambiguous formats (i. e. 2010-02-03 as potentially `%Y-%m-%d` or `%Y-%d-%m` for instance).