# Data frame with date field as a factor and mix of date values

Tags: r, datetime

I've a data frame with date field as factor and have mix of values as below. How can I standardize, convert into date format and extract month and year?

```
1  Oct 24 2013  3:59PM     
2  Nov  5 2013  3:00PM     
3  Nov 26 2013  1:00PM      
4  2015-05-05 21:09:00      
5  Nov 19 2013  1:00PM      
6  2015-05-28 20:23:00      
7  2015-05-28 20:24:00      
8  Nov 12 2013  1:00PM      
9  2015-05-28 20:29:00      
10 2015-05-28 20:26:00
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Nothing useful [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618004/convert-dates-with-different-formats-in-data-frame-over-multiple-columns), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764514/how-to-change-multiple-date-formats-in-same-column) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067761/format-a-date-column-in-a-data-frame)?

Answer (score 1):

You could try `parse_date_time()` from the *lubridate* package.  I find it makes dealing with multiple formats a lot easier.  It's just a matter of fiddling around with the `orders` argument.  Here we can use `c("mdyR", "ymdT")` for our `orders` vector.

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(df$V1, c("mdyR", "ymdT"))
# [1] "2013-10-24 15:59:00 UTC" "2013-11-05 15:00:00 UTC"
# [3] "2013-11-26 13:00:00 UTC" "2015-05-05 21:09:00 UTC"
# [5] "2013-11-19 13:00:00 UTC" "2015-05-28 20:23:00 UTC"
# [7] "2015-05-28 20:24:00 UTC" "2013-11-12 13:00:00 UTC"
# [9] "2015-05-28 20:29:00 UTC" "2015-05-28 20:26:00 UTC"
```

To extract the month and year, we, can do the following.

```
pdt <- parse_date_time(df$V1, c("mdyR", "ymdT"))
month(pdt)
# [1] 10 11 11  5 11  5  5 11  5  5
year(pdt)
# [1] 2013 2013 2013 2015 2013 2015 2015 2013 2015 2015
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(10L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 
6L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("2015-05-05 21:09:00", "2015-05-28 20:23:00", 
"2015-05-28 20:24:00", "2015-05-28 20:26:00", "2015-05-28 20:29:00", 
"Nov 12 2013  1:00PM", "Nov 19 2013  1:00PM", "Nov 26 2013  1:00PM", 
"Nov  5 2013  3:00PM", "Oct 24 2013  3:59PM"), class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

See if data can be parsed with one format (the default for `as.POSIXct.factor` in this case) and then try the other if unsuccessful:

```
 dats$dt2 <- as.POSIXct( # Needed b/c get numeric values from the `if(){}`; Why?
              sapply(trim(dats$dt),   # sjmisc:trim() only needed if have extra spaces
                function(d) if( !is.na( strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") ) ){
                       as.POSIXct(d)      } else {
                       as.POSIXct( d, format="%b %d %Y  %H:%M%p") }), origin="1970-01-01" )
```