# How to fast convert different time formats in large data frames?

Tags: r, performance, datetime-format

I want to calculate length in different time dimensions but I have problems dealing with the two slightly different time formats in my data frame column.

The original data frame column has about a million rows with the two formats (shown in the example code) mixed up .

Example code:

```
time <- c("2018-07-29T15:02:05Z", "2018-07-29T14:46:57Z",
         "2018-10-04T12:13:41.333Z", "2018-10-04T12:13:45.479Z")

length <- c(15.8, 132.1, 12.5, 33.2)

df <- data.frame(time, length)

df$time <- format(as.POSIXlt(strptime(df$time,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", tz="")))
df
```

The formats `"2018-10-04T12:13:41.333Z"` and `"2018-10-04T12:13:45.479Z"` result in `NA`.

Is there a solution that would also be applicable to a big data frame where the two formats are mixed up?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389139/format-multiple-date-formats-in-one-columns-using-lubridate

Comment: In base R you could remove values after dots with `gsub("\\..*Z", "Z", time)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `%OS` instead of `%S` to account for decimals in seconds.

```
help("strptime")
```

> Specific to R is `%OSn`, which for output gives the seconds truncated to
>   0 <= n <= 6 decimal places (and if %OS is not followed by a digit, it
>   uses the setting of getOption("digits.secs"), or if that is unset, n =
>   0).

```
as.POSIXct(time, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ")
# [1] "2018-07-29 15:02:05 CEST" "2018-07-29 14:46:57 CEST"
# [3] "2018-10-04 12:13:41 CEST" "2018-10-04 12:13:45 CEST"
```

This base R code is **considerably faster** than the package solutions, try it yourself.

#### Update 1

```
time2 <- c("2018-09-01T12:42:37.000+02:00", "2018-10-01T11:42:37.000+03:00")
```

This one is trickier. `?strptime` says we should use `%z` for offsets from UTC, but somehow it won't work with `as.POSIXct`. Instead we could do this,

```
as.POSIXct(substr(time2, 1, 23), format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS") + 
  {os <- as.numeric(el(strsplit(substring(time2, 24), "\\:")))
  (os[1]*60 + os[2])*60}
# [1] "2018-09-01 14:42:37 CEST" "2018-10-01 13:42:37 CEST"
```

which cuts the unreadable part from the string, converts it to seconds and adds it to the `"POSIXct"` object.

If there are *only* hours as in `time2`, we could also say:

```
as.POSIXct(substr(time2, 1, 23), format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS") + 
  as.numeric(substr(time2, 24, 26))*3600
# [1] "2018-09-01 14:42:37 CEST" "2018-10-01 13:42:37 CEST"
```

That the code is slightly longer now should not obscure the fact that it runs practically as fast as the one at top of the answer.

#### Update 2

You could wrap the current three variants into a function with `if (nchar(x) == 29) ... else` structure, such as this one:

```
fixDateTime <- function(x) {
  s <- split(x, nchar(x))
  if ("20" %in% names(s))
    s$`20` <- as.POSIXct(s$`20` , format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
  else if ("24" %in% names(s))
    s$`24` <- as.POSIXct(s$`24`, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ")
  else if ("29" %in% names(s))
    s$`29` <- as.POSIXct(substr(s$`29`, 1, 23), format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS") + 
      {os <- as.numeric(el(strsplit(substring(s[[3]], 24), "\\:")))
      (os[1]*60 + os[2])*60}
  return(unsplit(s, nchar(x)))
}

res <- fixDateTime(time3)
res
# [1] "2018-07-29 15:02:05 CEST" "2018-10-04 00:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-01 00:00:00 CEST"
str(res)
# POSIXct[1:3], format: "2018-07-29 15:02:05" "2018-10-04 00:00:00" "2018-10-01 00:00:00"
```

Compared to the packages only `fixDateTime` can handle all three defined date-time types. According to the concluding benchmark the function is still very fast.

***Note:*** The function logically fails if different date formats have the same `nchar`, and it should be customized in the case (e.g. by another `split` condition)! Not tested: daylight saving time behavior when adding seconds to `POSIXct`.

#### Benchmark

```
# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval  cld
# fixDateTime  35.46387  35.94761  40.07578  36.05923  39.54706  68.46211    10   c 
#  as.POSIXct  20.32820  20.45985  21.00461  20.62237  21.16019  23.56434    10  b   # to compare
#   lubridate  11.59311  11.68956  12.88880  12.01077  13.76151  16.54479    10 a    # produces NAs! 
#     anytime 198.57292 201.06483 203.95131 202.91368 203.62130 212.83272    10    d # produces NAs!
```

#### Data

```
time <- c("2018-07-29T15:02:05Z", "2018-07-29T14:46:57Z", "2018-10-04T12:13:41.333Z", 
"2018-10-04T12:13:45.479Z")
time2 <- c("2018-07-29T15:02:05Z", "2018-07-29T15:02:05Z", "2018-07-29T15:02:05Z") 
time3 <- c("2018-07-29T15:02:05Z", "2018-10-04T12:13:41.333Z", 
           "2018-10-01T11:42:37.000+03:00")
```

#### Benchmark code

```
n <-  1e3
t1 <- sample(time2, n, replace=TRUE)
t2 <- sample(time3, n, replace=TRUE)

library(lubridate)
library(anytime)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fixDateTime=fixDateTime(t2),
                               as.POSIXct=as.POSIXct(t1, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ"),
                               lubridate=parse_date_time(t2, "ymd_HMS"),
                               anytime=anytime(t2),
                               times=10L)
```

Comment: wow thats really frustrating - I have spend quite some time on this and now you´re telling me there is one additional letter I was missing
Thanks!

Comment: @Lasse You are welcome. It's a little hidden in the documentation of `?strptime`, penultimate paragraph before section "Value".

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I just came across another date format in my data frame column. Some of the rows have a date like this ```2018-09-01T12:42:37.000+02:00```. Is it possible to include that in ```as.POSIXct()``` as well?

Comment: @Lasse see update, I hope it's what you wanted. You could wrap this in a function with `if (nchar(x) == 29) ... else` structure.

Comment: I think I get your idea - yet the `if...else` structure does not seem to work for all formats (I also don´t know what `r` wants to tell me with `Error: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used` in this particular case. **My Example:** `t<- c("2018-07-29T15:02:05Z", "2018-10-04T12:13:41.333Z", "2018-10-01T11:42:37.000+03:00")` and the statement:
`if (nchar(t)==29) {as.POSIXct(substr(t, 1, 23), format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS") + as.numeric(substr(t, 24, 26))*3600} else {as.POSIXct(t, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ")}` 
I might also put this in another question. THANKS!

Comment: very nice solution! thank you so much for your effort!

Answer (score 2):

You can use library `anytime`

```
    library(anytime)
    time<- c("2018-07-29T15:02:05Z",
             "2018-07-29T14:46:57Z",
             "2018-10-04T12:13:41.333Z",
             "2018-10-04T12:13:45.479Z")
    anytime(time)
#[1] "2018-07-29 15:02:05 CEST" "2018-07-29 14:46:57 CEST" "2018-10-04 12:13:41 CEST" "2018-10-04 12:13:45 CEST"
```

Comment: thank you - unfortunately it takes ages for my big dataset to apply this command

Answer (score 2):

or you can also use:

```
time<- c("2018-07-29T15:02:05Z",
         "2018-07-29T14:46:57Z",
         "2018-10-04T12:13:41.333Z",
         "2018-10-04T12:13:45.479Z")

length<-c(15.8,132.1,12.5,33.2)

df<-data.frame(time,length)
library(lubridate)

# df$time2<-as_datetime(df$time)
df$time2 <-parse_date_time(df$time, "ymd_HMS") 
df
```