# Different timestamp factor to single date format

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have two different dates in a data.frame in the following format as factors "dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS" and "dd/m/yyyy hh:mm" and I'm trying to convert this into the same format using the `strptime`:

```
strptime(x = as.character(data.frame$timestamp),format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

but only "dd/m/yyyy hh:mm" is converting and the other timestamp results in `NA`.

Comment: Please share an extract of your data using `dput()` function with an example of dates well converted and not.

Comment: test<-data.frame("12/7/2008 11:21", "12/7/2008 21:08","23-09-2008 09:93:16","14-07-2008 21:57:28")


strptime(x = as.character(test),format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

Comment: output as Na Na Na Na

Comment: I think the problem is more concerning with the separator than the digits of months. In fact, when you have only a digit for month you have `/` as separator, and when you have two digits you have `-` as separator. Here you may find the solution to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764514/how-to-change-multiple-date-formats-in-same-column

Comment: in any case there is something weird with your third date: timestamp is 9h, 93m(?!?!?), and 16s...

Comment: @ScipioneSarlo That date is invalid in example. It should be corrected before trying solution. I have modified it be a valid date in answer.

Comment: @MKR I suppose too, but I think it's better to give him a code with its real data so when the parsing function (base R or `lubridate`) returns NAs he may consider whether (and how) to correct the real data he has to wrangle with.

Comment: @scipioneSarlo yes. You have already pointed out it to him and I'll modify my answer to use data from OP. I thought it could be typo in OP.

Comment: @MKR In fact one of the two votes is mine ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about your end goal. But you can use `lubridate` package to convert vector containing dates in mixed formats.

```
library(lubridate)
test<-data.frame(timestamp = c("12/7/2008 11:21", "12/7/2008 21:08",
"23-09-2008 09:13:16","14-07-2008 21:57:28"))
dates_df <- parse_date_time(test$timestamp, c("dmy HMS", "dmy HM"))
#>dates_df
#[1] "2008-07-12 11:21:00 UTC" "2008-07-12 21:08:00 UTC"
"2008-09-23 09:13:16 UTC" "2008-07-14 21:57:28 UTC"
```

Dates are converted and available in dates_df which can be converted or used per choice.