# Parse Text to DateTime then Convert Output from 12Hour Am/Pm to 24 Hour in Excel/R/Python

Tags: python, r, excel

I have about 1000 lines of data recorded in this format:
    2 Apr 2018, 23:14:17

And I have about another 1000 recorded like this:
    Mar 27, 2018, 10:42:26 PM

My first issue is that they are recognised by Excel as a character string (the original compiler of this document dumped a bunch of DateTimes in from somewhere else).

My second issue is that even after we successfully convert the format to be recognised as 'DateTime', I then need to change the format to DD:MM:YYYY hh:mm:ss in 24-hour rather than 12-hour time.

Your help with this or advice as to how I can rephrase the question is greatly appreciated. Tagging Excel, R and Python as these are the tools I have on-hand.

Comment: A lazy suggestion - you could try the [`dateparser`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dateparser) module for a quick fix. It will be slower than a tailored solution but it won't make a huge difference with your dataset size. Not at a PC to make a specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, the package [lubridate](http://lubridate.tidyverse.org/) is what you need.  Here is some example codes:

```
> require(lubridate)
# examples from the question statement.
> test_date_1 = "2 Apr 2018, 23:14:17"
> test_date_2 = "Mar 27, 2018, 10:42:26 PM"

# parse the date.
> date1 = dmy_hms(test_date_1)
> date2 = mdy_hms(test_date_2)

# show the date
> print(date1)
[1] "2018-04-02 23:14:17 UTC"
> print(date2)
[1] "2018-03-27 22:42:26 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you prefer plain R use `strptime`:

```
strptime("2 Apr 2018, 23:14:17", "%d %b %Y, %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2018-04-02 23:14:17 PDT"
strptime("Mar 27, 2018, 10:42:26 PM", "%b %d, %Y, %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2018-03-27 10:42:26 PDT"
```

Comment: I really appreciate this thank you! I can only select one, and I cant 'upvote' with my level of experience, but I just wanted to say thank you for showing me another way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The following example will give you a fair idea on how to fix your dates in `R` (with [lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html)), if you have your 1000 records in a data frame. The time will also be converted to a 24 hr format.

Test data frame for demonstration:

```
df <- data.frame(date = rep("2 Apr 2018, 23:14:17", 10))
temp <- data.frame(date = rep("Mar 27, 2018, 10:42:26 PM", 10))
df <- rbind(df, temp)
df
```

Fix the dates:

```
library(lubridate)

dmy <- dmy_hms(df$date)
mdy <- mdy_hms(df$date) 

mdy[is.na(mdy)] <- dmy[is.na(mdy)]

df$date <- mdy
```

Refer the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764514/how-to-change-multiple-date-formats-in-same-column) for further information.