# Converting date from factors to Date, tricky data

Tags: r, date, posixct

I have a data frame with dates and times in two different columns as factors - `df$date` and `df$time`. I'm able to convert `df$date` from factor to date format. However there's an issue with the `df$time` column. Some times are in the H:M:S format while some are in the HMS format. For eg row 1 has time 02:30:15 while row 2 has time 0345, row 3 might have something like 094530. (The colons are missing)

```
#converting into posixct format
df$newtime <-as.POSIXct(df$time,format="%H: %M :%S")
```

However this generates random dates but correct time, so I used `strptime` to remove years month and date

```
df$newtime1 <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(df$newtime,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="")) ,format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

This gives me correct time in hours minutes and seconds. However it generates a few NAs because some time rows don't have colons (0345 instead of 03:45)

The image shows my desired output

[image]

I want all times to be in `%H :%M :%S` format i.e `02:30:15, 03:45:00, 09:45:30`

Comment: It's difficult to help debug without a [workable sample of your data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). For working with multiple possible formats, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13764514/5325862) is likely a dupe, but right now it's unclear

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I've posted an image of the desired output

Comment: Please do *not* post images of input data  Follow the instructions for asking questions at the top of the [tag:r] tag.

Comment: use `lubridate::parse_date_time(df$newtime,c("ymdHM","ymdHMS"))`