# Search and mass convert character columns to date in R with dplyr without explicite specification

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate

I have a messy dataframe with thousand variables and want to automate conversion of specific columns to dates without having to specify which columns explicitely. All columns to convert have "Date" in their name. Most are `mdy` but they also can be `dmy`. Some contain errors, or malformatted dates but in a very very minor proportion <0.1%.

I tried:

```
df %>% select(contains("Date")) %>% as_Date() #Does not work
df %>%  select(contains("Date"))  %>% mdy() #selecting only the columns with dates, does not work
df %>% select(contains("Date")) %>% parse_date_time( c("mdy", "dmy")) #also does not work
```

I think I dont get something fundamental.

Comment: Have you tried `df[] <- lapply(df, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)` or `as.Date(df[,grep("Date", names(df))])`. Can you post example data?

Comment: Or, similarly, `df <- df %>% muate(across(contains("Date"), as.Date))`?  I think you need `across`, not `select`...

Comment: More info on how to deal with different date formats in the same field: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764514/how-to-change-multiple-date-formats-in-same-column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution based on `lubridate`:

Toy data:

```
df <- data.frame(Date1 = c("01-Mar-2015", "31-01-2012", "15/01/1999"), 
                 Var_Date = c("01-02-2018", "01/08/2016", "17-09-2007"), 
                 More_Dates = c("27/11/2009", "22-Jan-2013", "20-Nov-1987"))

# define formats:
formats <- c("%d-%m-%Y", "%d/%m/%Y", "%d-%b-%Y")
```

A `dyplr`solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("Date"), 
                ~ parse_date_time(., orders = formats))) %>%
  mutate(across(contains("Date"),
                ~ format(., "%d-%m-%Y")))
       Date1   Var_Date More_Dates
1 01-03-2015 01-02-2018 27-11-2009
2 31-01-2012 01-08-2016 22-01-2013
3 15-01-1999 17-09-2007 20-11-1987
```

A `base R`solution:

```
library(lubridate)
df[,grepl("Date", names(df))] <- apply(df[,grepl("Date", names(df))], 2, 
                  function(x) format(parse_date_time(x, orders = my_formats), "%d-%m-%Y"))
```

Comment: what to the two mutate commands do differently? whats the use of the 2 mutate commands? Thank you

Comment: The first converts all different formats to the Ymd format, the second converts that format to dmY.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `parse_date` from `parsedate`

```
library(parsedate)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), parse_date))
       Date1   Var_Date More_Dates
1 2015-03-01 2018-01-02 2009-11-27
2 2012-01-31 2016-01-08 2013-01-22
3 1999-01-15 2007-09-17 1987-11-20
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Date1 = c("01-Mar-2015", "31-01-2012", "15/01/1999"
), Var_Date = c("01-02-2018", "01/08/2016", "17-09-2007"), More_Dates = c("27/11/2009", 
"22-Jan-2013", "20-Nov-1987")),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```